# View laptop hardware statistics

Tags: macos, terminal

How can I return the temperatures, fan speeds, etc, using Terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This website claims to have a free commandline tool to monitor temperature sensors.

http://www.bresink.de/osx/0TemperatureMonitor/details.html

> tempmonitor command-line tool
>
> Temperature Monitor
>
> version for the BSD command-line of Mac OS X, temperature sensors only
>
> yes

(Name of tool; part of package download; description; free of charge?)

Comment: Wow, that tool is awesome! Funnily the guy who coded it was my computer graphics teaching assistent a decade ago :)

Answer (score -3):

Here's a website with a script:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20051021115356696

> While hunting around in ioreg I found a bunch of hardware sensor readouts, including CPU and GPU temperatures. I had no idea this stuff was available without a compiled app, so I excitedly whipped up a bash script (tp v0.1) to display the values.

Comment: Might have worked in 2005, but returns nothing on mid 2010 iMac with Lion. Looking at the script, `ioreg -n IOHWSensor` will not return expected values.

Comment: @koiyu - I agree.  I'll delete this answer.  (It'd be useful if it got another two downvotes.)

Comment: @Dan, there you go, 1 more down vote.

Comment: @DanBeale Why ?